# OpenMDAO + PyOptSparse compatibility

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, openmdao

I want to use the PyOptSparse driver. I have successfully installed the package, but did do with Python 2.7.

```
Lorens-MacBook-Pro:code lorensheets$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pyoptsparse import Optimization
>>>
```

My OpenMDAO installation is with Python 3.6. When I try to import the module though, this is the error I see:

```
>>> from openmdao.drivers.pyoptsparse_driver import pyOptSparseDriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openmdao/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pyoptsparse import Optimization
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyoptsparse'
>>>
```

I have tried an OpenMDAO installation with Python 2.7, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the error:

```
ImportError: No module named configparser
```

Does pyoptsparse need to be installed with python3 in order to work with OpenMDAO, or do I need to get OpenMDAO to work properly with Python 2.7? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, pyoptsparse is an external package. You can get it [from here.](https://bitbucket.org/mdolab/pyoptsparse) If you installed something in your 2.7 environment, it won't be available in 3, so you need to reinstall it there.

For 2.7, it looks like you need to also configparser. I thought that came with 2.7, but maybe it was somewhere later in 2.7.x. Anyway, you should be able to install it with pip:

```
pip install configparser
```

Comment: Kenneth, thanks for the info. Reinstalled pyoptsparse with Python3. 

Now getting this error when using nsga2 optimizer:

    """pyOptSparse Error: There was an error importing the compiled nsga2 
    module"""

Getting the same error for every pyoptsparse optimizer

Comment: It sounds like your modules didn't build properly. Make sure you did a 'python setup.py build' in the pyoptsparse directory. Did you get any messages that inicate that none of the c or fortran code compiled?